# Why do we discuss ANOVA and completely randomized design together?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, causality

It is common that textbook discusses completely randomized design and ANOVA together. However, it is not clear to me at all how does CRD "translate" to ANOVA. For example, does CRD imply that the model has to have form $y_{ij} = \mu + \tau_i + \epsilon_{ij}$? Does CRD imply that $\epsilon_{ij}$ has to be iid normally distributed?

On the other hand, it also puzzles me that why we don't discuss CRD with the notion of "assignment mechanism" (as in Rubin causal model) at the same time. It seems a little bit strange to me that we first discuss how we assign experiment units according to CRD, then suddenly we just say "let's assume that $y_{ij} = \mu + \tau_i + \epsilon_{ij}$...".

If anyone can point out the connection between ANOVA model and CRD, that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to CV! I think this question would benefit from an edit to provide a quote + citation illustrating that it "…is common that textbook discusses…".

Comment: I want to test the null hypothesis that mean weights at birth are the same for boys and girls. I go to a hospital and observed and recorded the weights and gender of newborns. Assuming the weights in each gender are normal distributed, I can use ANOVA absolutely, but I did not use CRD.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has not answered the reasonable question in the comments, and has not been on the site in years.

Comment: @Peter An answer was offered in the comment (it's the same individual).

Comment: @whuber  Where is that?  Alexis asked for a quote and citation to back up the claim that this is a common practice.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for being more specific about what you meant.  A citation would indeed be helpful; however, to understand and answer this question I don't think it's necessary.